# Object angular assign value

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working in Angular 16. The query is performed on the database and assign the returned number to document number.

model

```
export class document {
    doc_data: string ="";
    doc_for: string="";
    doc_number: number = 0;
    doc_year: number = 0;
    doc_subject: string = "";
    doc_send: number = 0;
    doc_employee: number = 0;
}
```

file Service

```
number_doc(year: number): any {
    // return the value
    return this.http.get(`${this.url + 'numberdoc'}/${year}`).pipe(
        map((res) => {
        let resInt = +res;
        return resInt;
      })
    );
  }
```

file app

```
export class AppComponent {
  ...
   doc = new document();
  ...

 find_number_doc(year: number): number {
    return this.service.number_doc(year).subscribe((res: number) => {
      //this.number_doc = res;
      this.doc_number = res;
      return res;
    });
  }

ngOnInit() {

    //initialization of some properties. I put it more as the shape you are assigning
    this.year = formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy');
    this.doc.doc_data = formatDate(new Date(), 'dd/MM/yyyy');
    this.doc.doc_year = new Date(), 'yyyy';

}


onClick() {
      ...
      this.find_number_doc(this.year);

      
      this.document.download(this.doc);

}
```

It is returning the database number. I am unable to assign it to the property.
In the first call the property "this.doc_number", when it is passed to the child component, it is passed "0". When calling for the second time, pass the number
previous.

```
Object => 0
document.service.ts:47 ---- Objecto -----
document.service.ts:48 {"doc_data":"02/11/2023","doc_for":"","doc_number":0,"doc_year":2023,"doc_subject":"","doc_send":0,"doc_employee":0}
document.service.ts:179 Blob {size: 8593, type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'}
document.service.ts:181 Document created successfully
app.component: 29
```

The number 29 should have been passed, but 0 was passed.

Second

```
Object =>29
document.service.ts:47 ---- Objecto  -----
document.service.ts:48 {"docdata":"02/11/2023","doc_for":"","doc_number":29,"doc_year":2023,"doc_subject":"","doc_send":0,"doc_employee":0}
document.service.ts:179 Blob {size: 8594, type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'}
document.service.ts:181 Document created successfully
app.component.ts:131 app.component: 30
```

The number 30 should have been passed, but 29 was passed. I researched and even tried to switch to another variable but it got complicated.

```
30
document.service.ts:47 ---- Objecto -----
document.service.ts:48 {"doc_data":"02/11/2023","doc_for":"","doc_number":30,"doc_year":2023,"doc_subject":"","doc_send":0,"doc_employee":0}
document.service.ts:179 Blob {size: 8594, type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document'}
document.service.ts:181 Document created successfully
app.component.ts:131 app.component: 31
```

The number 31 should have been passed, but 30 was passed.

I am trying to pass the number returned from the database to generate a word document. I already researched, before posting, trying to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

The return type for the function `find_number_doc` based on your code says it is going to return a `number` but in reality, it is returning a `Subscription`.

Since you are subscribing to the service function call with `subscribe`, `find_number_doc()` should have a return type of `void`, because it shouldn't return anything, additionally, the name for this function should be changed to `setNumberDoc()` or similar, if you name it as `findSomething()` I would assume the function is going to return a value, which is not the case.

If `doc_number` is going to be eventually filled with a value from the backend, then you have 2 ways to handle this situation:

*reactive approach*

```js
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent {
  docNumber$!: Observable<number | undefined>;
  
  setDocNumber(year: number): void {
    this.docNumber$ = this.service.number_doc(year);
  }
}
```

```html
<child-component [theDocumentNumber]="docNumber$ | async"></child-component>
```

In this approach, you don't `subscribe` manually to the `observable`, instead, you let the `async` pipe take care of that without even worrying about the `Subscription`. You just grab the observable from the server, and the template HTML along with the `async` pipe will **react** to any value changes that might happen.

*imperative approach*

```js
@Component({...})
export class ParentComponent implements OnDestroy {
   docNumber = 0;
   private _sub = new Subscription();

   setDocNumber(year: number): void {
     this._sub.add(
       this.service.number_doc(year).subscribe(res => this.docNumber = res)
     );
   }

   ngOnDestroy(): void {
     this._sub?.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

```html
<child-component [theDocumentNumber]="docNumber"></child-component>
```

Here, you `subscribe` manually to the service `observable`, and you **should** take care of the `Subscription` in order to avoid any memory leak.

A couple of observations, if you are going to use `class`, `interface`, `type`, and others, these should be named starting with a capital letter so

`export class document` should be `export class Document`

The naming convention in `javascript/typescript` is usually with `camelCase`, so instead of `find_number_doc` should be `findNumberDoc`, and try to name your functions with a **verb**. Your service function `number_doc` doesn't say anything... it should be `getNumberDoc`, `retrieveNumberDoc`, etc... they start with a verb (get, retrieve)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I changed it as needed but it still takes the previous value.  ````Angular is running in development mode.
app.component.ts:277 ---- this.docNumber ----
app.component.ts:278 0 ````  ````Document created successfully
app.component.ts:277 ---- this.docNumber ----
app.component.ts:278 34````